# Please help to extract date using xpath

Tags: xpath

```xml
<div class='postbodytop">
   
  <a class="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" href="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx">tonyd</a>
   
  "posted this 4 minutes ago "
   
  <span class="hidden-xs"> </span>  
  
</div>
```

Hello, I want to extract the "posted this 4 minutes ago" or just "4 minutes" using xpath. Can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: Please, take some time to read [how to ask](/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: this isn't even valid XML.

Answer (score 0):

The `div` whose class equals `postbodytop` contains three child nodes: a `span`, a text node, and another `span`. Your path should start at the `div` and then select the child text node, for which the appropriate test is `text()`.

```xml
div/text()
```

Of course this is just a fragment of a bigger page, and your XPath may need to have something at the start e.g. `/html/body/` etc. and if there are other `div` elements at the same level as the `<div class=postbodytop>`, then you should be more specific about the `div`, e.g. `div[@class="postbodytop"]` instead of just `div` in that XPath expression.